# Azure Media Services - Captions on iOS - Native not AMP

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, azure-media-services

I'm trying to get captioning working on iOS and Android. Android seems relatively straight forward but I can't seem to figure out how (nor do the docs really tell you) to setup WebVTT captions like you can easily do with Windows 10 UWP and AMP.

On Android I am just doing videoView.AddSubtitleSource and it appears to work. On iOS I'm at a loss. From what I can tell it appears that it's possible to load captions not embedded in the file, but I can't find any example of how it works with MediaSelectionOptions and specifying a stream or similar.

I've done this in my own custom renderer in Xamarin Forms but I'm fine converting it from swift or Objective C if needed.

Anyone get this working or know how?

Answer (score 1):

If your interest is iOS native player, check this tutorial video from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/512/ (about 20 min into it)

If your interest is Safari based player, check the examples here: https://developer.apple.com/streaming/examples/ (3 of the examples include webVTT)

Comment: This doesn't really give an examples and the docs at Apple have the same problem. They tell you all about selecting one, but they don't tell you how to add one and have the controls allow you to select. Hence my problem. Seems like a lot of hand waiving. I *think* that using AVMutableComposition is the way to go but I'm just guessing and trying stuff now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with iOS and Safari not playing back VTT side car files appears to be fixed now in the latest iOS release. Not sure exactly when it was fixed, but I'm on 14.7.1  and the following sample is working now

https://ampdemo.azureedge.net/azuremediaplayer.html?url=%2F%2Famssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net%2Fbc57e088-27ec-44e0-ac20-a85ccbcd50da%2FTearsOfSteel.ism%2Fmanifest&subtitles=English,en,%2F%2Famssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net%2Fbc57e088-27ec-44e0-ac20-a85ccbcd50da%2FTOS-en.vtt;Spanish,es,%2F%2Famssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net%2Fbc57e088-27ec-44e0-ac20-a85ccbcd50da%2FTOS-es.vtt;French,fr,%2F%2Famssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net%2Fbc57e088-27ec-44e0-ac20-a85ccbcd50da%2FTOS-fr.vtt;Italian,it,%2F%2Famssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net%2Fbc57e088-27ec-44e0-ac20-a85ccbcd50da%2FTOS-it.vtt